# MongoDB - Pivot data down instead of flattening with aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can we unwind/flatten both old and new arrays and pivote data down like the below examples, consider both arrays might have different sizes and order. Looking for a solution in mongo aggregation query

**Ex.1:
JSON/Object**

```
{
    "sno": "1001",
    "owner": "Tim",
    "old": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "age": "20"
        },
        {
            "name": "Park",
            "age": "40"
        }
    ],
    "new": [
        {
            "name": "Snow",
            "age": "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "age": "25"
        },
        {
            "name": "New Rec",
            "age": "55"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**

```
sno     owner   current_name    current_age     renew_name  renew_age
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1001    Tim     John            20              Snow        10
1001    Tim     Park            40              Mike        25
1001    Tim                                     New Rec     55
```

**Ex.2:
JSON/Object**

```
{
    "sno": "1001",
    "owner": "Tim",
    "old": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "age": "20"
        },
        {
            "name": "Park",
            "age": "40"
        }
    ],
    "new": [
        {
            "name": "Snow",
            "age": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**

```
sno     owner   current_name    current_age     renew_name  renew_age
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1001    Tim     John            20              Snow        10
1001    Tim     Park            40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields
- `$range` to make array from 0 to total max element size of `old` or `new` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of the above range
- `$arrayElemAt` to select the object of the specific element from `old` and `new` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `names` array
- `$project` to format your result and show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      sno: 1,
      owner: 1,
      names: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [0,
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $gt: [{ $size: "$old" }, { $size: "$new" }] },
                  { $size: "$old" },
                  { $size: "$new" }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          in: {
            old: { $arrayElemAt: ["$old", "$$this"] },
            new: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$new", "$$this"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$names" },
  {
    $project: {
      sno: 1,
      owner: 1,
      current_name: "$names.old.name",
      current_age: "$names.old.age",
      renew_name: "$names.new.name",
      renew_age: "$names.new.age"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VMZH9Tj1l10)